# php - parse EXIF data?

Tags: php

I get the EXIF data of images

```
'ExposureTime' => string '10/150' (length=6)
'FNumber' => string '35/10' (length=5)
'ISOSpeedRatings' => int 100
'FocalLength' => string '180/10' (length=6)
```

What should i do to it look like below

```
Focal Length  18mm
Exposure Time 1/15 sec
ISO- Speed ISO-100
F-Number = F/3.5
```

So is there a library php allow me read and parse data to look like when i view image's properties ? or some rules for me calculate base on it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: @ajreal: I get data by that function , but i want show it like above question .

Comment: -1, you can do the calculation using the data returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should i do to it look like below

you should convert received values to numbers and display them in a proper way. where's the problem?